# Using service accounts on Compute Engine instances

Tags: google-compute-engine

I'm trying to do `gcloud init` on my fresh GCE instance using a service account that I've created in the Developers Console. In the Developers Console, I see a few service accounts under **Permissions**, which I can't generate private key files for; I also see a service account that I made under **Service accounts** which I *can* get private keys for.

When I do `gcloud init` on the GCE instance, under "Pick credentials to use", I only see the service accounts in the Permissions tab (for which I don't have private keys). I'd like to use the service account that I have private keys for.

I can log in with my personal account for now, but this isn't scalable. Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elaborating on @Kamaran's answer after further discussion.

The basic solution is to enable the service account **on the GCE instance**.

First use `gcloud compute copy-files <private json key file> <instance name>:remote/path/to/key` to copy the file to the remote instance. Then run `gcloud auth activate-service-account <service account address> --key-file remote/path/to/key` command on the remote. The new service account will then be available in the `gcloud init` menu.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [gcloud auth activate-service-account](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/activate-service-account) command to get credentials via the private key for a service account. For more information and example please visit [this link](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/crypto?hl=en#creation).